# Netplan/ubuntu explained

Tags: networking, netplan, static-ip

I am still learning. My intent with the following netplan/ubuntu setup was to change my ip address to my ubuntu VM server (ubuntu 18.04) so I cut and pasted the following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [192.168.0.215/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

I am on a qnap NAS using VirtualizationStation 3. Now I cannot boot my ubuntu and I am presented  with a login screen to what appears to be a login to libvirt Quem.

I am not sure what each line of this configuration does so could someone explain what each line does so I might be able to boot into ubuntu.  As I researched everywhere I am sure this may help others as well.

Comment: Each line is self-explanatory...if you already understand basic networking. For example, 'dhcp': Either you know what it is or you don't. Your favorite Search Engine will happily present you with many basic networking primers. Your question, as currently written, is simply asking us to repeat our favorite networking primers to you.

Comment: The two lines that are not self-explanatory are 2 (version) and 3 (renderer). Yours are correct for an ordinary server. Don't change them.

Comment: You might also want to consider asking QNAP technical support (i.e., their forums).  Perhaps there is something they're doing that makes it "special"?

Comment: Sorry  user535733 that did not answer my question. I am at least trying to get beyond the libvirt Qemu menu that is asking for a password.. In hopes that the ubuntu server might proceed with booting .

Comment: netplan can will give you syntax checking if you run 'netplan generate' which is helpful.. there is also a 'netplan --debug generate'  or when that passes 'netplan --debug apply'.

Though I recommend that you only run netplan apply from the console as running it over a network connection when you reset networking might end up in a hung connection.

Comment: Thanks Simon! For Others:some yaml_basics.htm  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_basics.htm

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here, besides what is already found in the examples and reference on the [netplan.io](https://netplan.io/) site?

Comment: @user535733 What's wrong with the indentation of line #1? Inquiring mind want to know :-)

Comment: @cal After placing the .yaml file into /etc/netplan/, did you do a `sudo netplan generate`, a `sudo netplan apply`, and `reboot`?

Comment: @heynnema it was fixed in a prior edit